# Is there a way to change the time format in chat from 24-hour to 12-hour?

Tags: support, chat, time

In chat, I see military time (24 hours format) next to a person's chat:

> [image]

Is it possible to change this time to non-military time? (e.g. 10:31 PM and 10:52 PM in the above.)

Comment: It's 24-hour time. It's only military time if you have martial law

Comment: Well, the transcript is showing the "non military" time.

Comment: @random if it matters that much, I can change it. I live in murica, and have only seen it referred to as military time.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked through the tabs in the chat profile options, and setting a time zone and format doesn't seem to be possible in chat, much like on the main site.

## However

This does **not** mean there is no answer. It simply means that there are no ways to convert the date *from your profile settings.* There are *undoubtedly* [at least a dozen browser extensions and userscripts](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&client=safari&hl=en-us&biw=1024&bih=672&ei=C7NQWK7dM4Sba_29uYgB&q=browser+extension+to+convert+dates+into+local+time&oq=browser+extension+to+convert+dates+into+local+tiem&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.33i21k1j33i160k1.25007.40619.0.42178.35.32.3.0.0.0.655.8296.2-28j2j0j2.32.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.31.7135...0j41j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1.gbBQuNTod-Q) to do precisely this. You could probably write your own, too, as it would be a simple matter of a regular expression to identify dates and a method to convert it to local time in the format that you desire.